# change field's number of values per role

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm wondering how to limit photo's number of values in my user's gallery type.

I want to have max 10 photos to basic users, and 30 for vip users.

Is there any chance to make it by drupal option or i should rewrite some javascript?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This continues on Jame's suggestion of using hook_form_alter().  I needed a solution like this before so I was driven to give it a try.  This isn't fully tested, but it does work as far as giving you control over how many upload fields to display.  I'm using it with an image field limit set to 10, on D6 and CCK.

The catch though is that CCK will display up to 10 upload fields, but when you set it to unlimited, it shows 1 field, and then uses the 'add another' button. So, if you use 10, then you can limit below that, but if you wanted to go from 30 to 10 you would need a different solution.

Sorry it's not an exact solution, but it may get you a little closer.  This code limits an image field with a limit of 10, down to 4, programmatically.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'mycontenttype_node_form') {

    // run some logic to figure out how many uploads, and set it here
    $number_of_uploads = 4;

    // not sure if this does anything, but it is the part of the field that
    // references the upload limit. it does not automatically add or remove
    // fields though
    $form['#field_info']['field_myimagefield']['multiple'] = $number_of_uploads;

    // just an increment var
    $i = 1;

    // we have to unset the fields from here
    foreach ($form['field_myimagefield'] as $key => $value) {
      // check for is_numeric because some are property keys starting with #
      if (is_numeric($key)) {
        if ($i > $number_of_uploads) {
          unset($form['field_myimagefield'][$key]);
        }

        $i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let us know if you go down this path.  I don't have time for full testing right now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing something like this would be to create two different gallery content types, permitting basic users the type which allows for 10 photos, and vip users the type which allows for 30.

However, this creates a problem whenever a person "upgrades."  They could then create a new gallery, but they would need to re-upload all 30 photos.

If the site isn't high-volume, you could simply inform users that you'll manually move their photos for them.

Of course, this is a lot of work for you, but it would spare you having to create a small custom module, if you aren't yet ready to go down this path (though if you know php, it's easier than it might sound).

The other option would be to use a combination of Drupal's [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) - this is assuming you're using CCK, or that whatever gallery module you're using has all the upload fields in one form -  `hook_form_alter()` would check your user's roles, and trim the form down from 30 to 10 photos in the case they're not in the vip role; and `hook_nodeapi()`, after checking the role id of the owner of the gallery node, would only display the first 10 photos, and not 30.  This would save you a lot of time in the long run, but requires creating a little module for this purpose.

If not all upload fields are in one form, you could always check to see how many images a user had already uploaded against their roles, and then conditionally display the controls for adding new images.  There are a number of ways one would do this depending on various circumstances ... it could be as easy as adding the role names to your body classes, and then using css to get rid of unwanted elements (if you aren't too picky about people "hacking" into the HTML to add their images, which is likely to happen very, very rarely) - or editing the templating code of whatever module you're using.

Comment: Are you sure "the other option" would work?  i.e. have you done this? This would definitely be the cleanest option. If you have a code example, please show it.  I tried using hook_form_alter to do something similar, but could not get it working.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any code to show.  I have used hook_form_alter() quite a lot, and it is sometimes a pain to use - especially when you're trying to use it in combination with cck.  If you use it with cck, you may need to change your module's weight so it runs after cck, since cck will be modifying the form itself.

Comment: I've used hook_form_alter() with CCK a lot.  If you're not sure, I'd remove that suggestion from your answer because I don't think it is that easy, making your answer inaccurate.. and that is coming from someone who has actually tried it. The need wasn't that important, so I did not pursue it.

Comment: OK, I'll modify - I guess one problem here is I don't know how you're creating your galleries - and what I suggest is really only applicable if you'll make them with CCK - now that I think about it, you're probably making them with the standard image / gallery module (I don't tend to do it that way, I think the out-of-the-box gallery module probably isn't used that frequently in more advanced sites, but I may be wrong).

Comment: I added about the contingency in which this advice can be used (I think probably not your case), and extra info if it's a different type case.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected (i think) ...It was bothering me so I tackled it again, and may have a code solution.  I'll post another answer so I can post code.